# Formatting grep output. Bash

Tags: bash, grep, formatting

trying to format output from grep to make it look better, code is

```
grep "$1" "$2" | grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" | sort | uniq -c
```

```
$ bash myScript.sh "Failed password for root" /home/user/auth.log 
      5 108.166.98.9
   1426 108.53.208.61
      1 113.108.211.131
      1 117.79.91.195
    370 122.224.49.124
   3480 144.0.0.32
     11 162.144.94.250
      6 162.253.66.74
      3 186.67.83.58
      1 222.190.114.98
    205 59.90.242.69
    705 60.172.228.226
      3 64.251.21.104
```

and want it to look more like

```
ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx attempts: X
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following command to the end of your pipe in your script, after `uniq`:

```
... | awk '{print "ip: " $2 " attempts: " $1}'
```

The output will be

```
ip: 108.166.98.9 attempts: 5
ip: 108.53.208.61 attempts: 1426
...
```

Comment: Perhaps `printf ( "ip: %15s attempts: %s", $2, $1)`